# How to get custom View's width when layout_width is wrap_content?

Tags: android, layout, view, width, onmeasure

Let's say we have our custom View declared in XML and we override its onMeasure() method:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    // Maximal length of line is width of this View 
    width = this.getLayoutParams().width;
```

If XML attribute `android:layout_width="100px"` is set then **width** returns value 100. But if attribute is `android:layout_width="match_parent"` or `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` then it returns -1 or -2. So how can we get measured width of this View in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
```